# Navigate from one Razor page to another Razor page with button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Is there a better way to navigate from one Razor page to different Razor page when a `button` is clicked. I want to navigate from `Index.cshtml` to `Inventory.cshtml` when the button is clicked.

Below is the current solution that I have managed use that works, but I am not sure if this is correct way. Reference used: https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/basics/razor-pages/

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<!--Page redirect-->
<form method="post" asp-page="Index">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-cta">View Inventory</button>
</form>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace TheInventory.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        //Page redirect on button form submit
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("Inventory");
        }
    }
}
```

Inventory.cshtml

```
@page
@model TheInventory.Pages.InventoryModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Inventory";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>This is the Inventory Page</p>
```

Comment: you can do it in the client side, in javascript. Also create an anchor a set the asp-controller and asp-action and there you redirect. Or create an anchor a and hard code the path. check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @user123456 Thank you for your reply. I will have a look at the link provided and try to use your solution provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve my problem I used the `asp-page` attribute with Razor Pages and set an anchor tag's `href` attribute value to the specific page.

Reference used: [asp.net core anchor tag helper - Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
<a asp-page="/PageExample">Page Example</a>
```

I wrapped the anchor tag element in the button element and was able to navigate to the specified page when the button was clicked.

Here is an snippet of my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-cta"><a asp-page="/Inventory">Manage Inventory</a></button>
```